# Why does array.map() function not change the array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add one to each element of my array. I tried:

```
myArray=[1,2,3]
myArray.map(a=>a+=1) // tried a++ and a=a+1 too
console.log(myArray) // return [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
```

it doesn't worked...
so i did that :

```
myArray=[1,2,3]
mySecondArray=[]
myArray.map(a=>mySecondArray.push(a+1))
console.log(mySecondArray) // return [ 2, 3, 4 ]
```

So it worked, but I don't anderstand why the first one didn't. Can you explain me why?

Comment: `Array.map` returns the mapped array. You can do `arr = arr.map(...)` if you want to set the array to its mapped version.

Comment: Because map doesn't change the original array. It returns another one.

Comment: Try `myArray = myArray.map(a=>a+=1)`. map returns a new array.

Comment: You can use `myArray.forEach((_, i) => myArray[i] += 1)` to mutate the array, but I wouldn't recommend it. Instead replace the current variable with a mapped version of the array, like shown in the answers below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `map()` method in JavaScript creates an array by calling a specific function on each element present in the parent array. It is a **non-mutating method**, that's why your first approach didn't work.

```
let myArray = [1,2,3];
myArray = myArray.map(x => x + 1);
console.log(myArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to equate it back :

```
myArray = myArray.map(a => a+1);
console.log(myArray)
```

output --- > [2, 3, 4]

Comment: `a => a + 1` is enough

Comment: yes, my bad, have changed it

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are not storing the instance.

Store the instance in some array,

```
let myArray=[1,2,3]
myArray = myArray.map(a=>a+1);
console.log(myArray);
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `+=` it only introduces confusion. I suggest changing it to a `+`.